# Power BI - Embed link for a dashboards, NOT reports

Tags: powerbi, embed, dashboard

I see that it is very complicated to get an embedded view for a dashboard in Power BI.

For reports, they generate a link for an embed view. So simple. There's no option for that within Power BI for dashboards.

Is there a way that a dashboard can be embedded? I am not familiar with packages or visual studio. If anyone can please guide me through the process step by step, if possible. I have checked documentations from Microsoft and it seems a bit complex. I have downloaded visual studio already. Now I am just stuck from there. I have a Power BI account already.

My main goal is to obtain/generate a link so that my dashboard can be embedded. Please help if possible. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can only embedded reports, not dashboards into, for example, SharePoint and Teams.

If you wish to embed dashboards or reports or components from them you will need Power BI Embedded or Premium, to allocate the workspace to a capacity, and have to create your own web portal to display them.

Comment: Hi @Jonee, I do have Power BI Premium. Would it be possible if you show me the steps if I have a premium account?

Comment: No it is not possible to show the steps. You need to create a web portal to host it. It is not a simple task that can be outlined in steps. A starting place is here https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html

Comment: @Dee The steps are shown under your other question.